# WPF Toggle switch default value depending on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my xaml code, I have a toggle switch and I need to set a default value under certain conditions.

For example, if the user checked a checkbox for a test type "A", my toggle switch value needs to be set on "Yes" by default. And conversely.

How can I set this default value ?

Here is the part of my code for the toggle switch :

```
<dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit Name="ToggleSwitchEdit" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=PathName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      CheckedStateContent="Yes" UncheckedStateContent="No" ContentPlacement="Both"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Id">
</dxe:ToggleSwitchEdit>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Test type"? Can you explain more on this?

Comment: My program can actually run different tests, which can be roughly assimilated to different comparisons. What I need is to set my toggle switch default value to "Yes" when the user choose to run test "A" for example. The test type is chosed  by the user thanks to a checkbox.

Comment: It's fascinating how, 3 years later i want to use dxe:ToggleSwitch - to allow user to edit a test type :D

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code and see what you must change to get it to work:

```
 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <CheckBox Content="Master" x:Name="Master"></CheckBox>
     <CheckBox Content="Slave"  x:Name="Slave" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Master, Path=IsChecked,  Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
 </StackPanel>
```

"Slave" checkBox is Binded to Master in twoWay Manner. you can set ElementName in above code and make it to work in your project.